# Is there a slick way to turn List<int?> into List<int> without a loop?

Tags: c#

Is there a slick way to turn `List<int?>` where non-null, into `List<int>` without a loop?

Comment: When you say without a loop do you mean a manual loop or avoiding any looping over the elements whatsoever?

Comment: The question is... you need to be certain of what you want to do with the `int?`s where `HasValue == false`. Austin's solution below discards them, which is fine. But another solution would be to provide a default value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here there's no loop in *your* code.  This will discard null values based on the *where non-null* part of your question.

```
var values = given.Where(n => n.HasValue).Select(n => n.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Alternatively, `given.Select(x => x ?? 0).ToList()` if you want to preserve the null entries as `0`.

Comment: @KirkWoll Bingo. +1 to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
var result = myList.Select(x => x ?? default(int)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no reference conserving cast to do this. `List<int>` and `List<int?>` are distinct incompatible types.

You need to create a copy which implies using a loop (directly or indirectly). Using LINQ avoids the explicit loop in your code, but obviously it still uses a loop internally.